# How to create Helper App and attach it to the main bundle in OSX?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I've read every post about the argument, but I can't find a solution (and a good Documentation!)

I don't know how to produce the Helper app executable in the right way.

At the moment I'm just running the Helper app in "release" mode, than copying the product Helper app.app into the Main app within a "Copy Files" build phase.

Is this the right way?

Running in this way the app works but I get errors validating the Main.app

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you release your helper 'application' as a helper library?